# Error building cordova getting "nodevars.bat is not recognized" and "Invalid attribute predicate"

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am getting an error while building a new version of my Cordova project in VS2015(Update 2).

Description:

```
"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\vs-npm\2.14.9"\nodevars.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file."
```

File:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets   (Line:285)
```

Log:

```
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: Invalid attribute predicate
1>  Error Invalid attribute predicate
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Google found nothing,

Does anybody have an idea?

UPDATE:

Now(for unknown reason) only the second error("Error Invalid attribute predicate") is showing. Still can't build =\

UPDATE 2:
I have hard-uninstalled vs2015_2 and installed vs15 Preview and the same error occurs.

Comment: Have you mentioned right installation path of visual studio in your environment variables? Is this path valid - C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools ??

Comment: i meant whether you have mentioned the proper installation path of visual studio in your 'path' environmental variable.

Comment: http://upimg.org/?di=FTAV

Comment: nodejs folder location is added in path environment variable?

Comment: yes: C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\

Comment: is that the right and valid path? are you able to execute node command successfully in command prompt?

Comment: jus check if any of this link helps - http://massivescale.com/quick-tip-microsoft-mda-targets-not-found-error/ https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9d7a6d3d-3868-493b-9f5e-a61ef0b3d26f/npm-errors-while-compiling-visual-studio-cordova-app?forum=ToolsForApacheCordova

Comment: node works from cmd. neither of those helped.

Comment: Could you try running 'npm cache clean' first and then run build command using administrator privilege?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109620/discussion-between-dorad-and-gandhi).

Comment: I think this may be an XML parsing error - can you post the contents of your config.xml file?

Comment: Hi Jordan, I still don't know what exactly was the problem in the xml(Just replaced it with a templated one and will move each detail slowly from the old one). But you were right.
Post it as an answer and receive your bounty. Thx man.

Comment: @dorad "nodevars.bat is not recognized" error is sure to do with path variables. How did you managed to fixed that? Chat links helped?

Comment: i don't know how it was gone. I have tried so many things... Thx anyway!

Comment: @dorad "Invalid attribute predicate"  error should be due to some illegal character in config.xml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109620/discussion-between-dorad-and-gandhi)
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From some [searches online](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=%22Error+Invalid+attribute+predicate%22) it looks like the message "Error Invalid attribute predicate" is coming from some XML parsing code. I'd look at config.xml and see if it appears to contain invalid XML anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed this issue by clearing the cordova cache from visual studio.

From tools->settings->tools for apache cordova->cordova tools click clear cordova cache

Comment: didn't help in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It was due to a corrupted node installation. I went to `C:\Users\luis-\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\vs-npm\2.14.9` and deleted everything. Then clean and deploy.

Answer (score 1):

"Invalid attribute predicate" error should be due to some illegal character in config.xml.